# How to prevent "Could not update ICEauthority file /home/[username]/.ICEauthority" when disk is full

Tags: 12.04

Our users have the possibility to login via Windows or Ubuntu 12.04. If their home drive is full, they get the error on Ubuntu "Could not update ICEauthority file /home/[username]/.ICEauthority" and they are not able to login. On Windows they still can login.

Is it possible to let them login on Ubuntu 12.04 even if their home drive is full?

(They don't know about shell, so this is not a solution. And "they could use Windows to free some space" is not a solution too.)

Comment: Ehm. How come their /home/ is filled up? What is the a limit on the size of their /home?

Comment: Each user has 1 GB of space. But is this relevant?